# How to allow sorting of multiple columns in Gtk.ListStore

Tags: python, gtk3

I have the following setup for a Gtk3 Listore which works.

```
    self.liststore = Gtk.ListStore(str, str, bool)
    treeview = Gtk.TreeView(model=self.liststore)

    renderer_text = CellRendererText()
    column_text = Gtk.TreeViewColumn("Media URL", renderer_text, text=0)
    treeview.append_column(column_text)


    column_date = Gtk.TreeViewColumn("Date", renderer_text, text=1)
    column_date.pack_start(renderer_text, True)
    treeview.append_column(column_date)


    renderer_toggle = Gtk.CellRendererToggle()
    renderer_toggle.connect("toggled", self.on_cell_toggled)
    column_toggle = Gtk.TreeViewColumn("Toggle", renderer_toggle, active=2)
    treeview.append_column(column_toggle)

    self.treeview = treeview
    self.scrolledwindow.add(self.treeview)
```

And I try to add:

```
     column_text.set_sort_column_id(0)
     self.liststore.set_sort_func(0,self.compare, None)
```

And this causes a crash, But according to the documentation here: http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/treeview.html that should work, however it works only if I replace the 0 with a 1 in the self.liststore.set_sort_func(0,self.compare, None) and I can click the Media column to sort the contents.

```
      self.liststore.set_sort_func(1,self.compare, None)
```

QUESTION: Is this correct or is this strange or is the documentation wrong and the index into the model does not start from 0 as is in the docs?

But moreover, I need help to allow sorting via the Date column. I have tried adding:

```
       column_date.set_sort_column_id(0)
       self.liststore.set_sort_func(1,self.compare, None)
```

but doing so fails with a crash.

Comment: It seems that this is a bug on my gtk build on the mountain lion. The proper way as is documented in http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/treeview.html works fine when in Fedora17 but causes a crash on Mountain Lion.